# Sum of subsequences recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Over the weekend I was working on the Ad Infinitum challenge on HackerRank.

One problem was to calculate the sum of all subsequences of a finite sequence, if each subsequence is thought of as an integer.

For example, sequence 4,5,6 would give answer 4 + 5 + 6 + 45 + 46 + 56 + 456 = 618.

I found a recursion and wrote the Python code below. It solved 5/13 test cases.

The remaining 8/13 test cases had runtime errors.

I was hoping someone could spy where in the code the inefficiencies lie, and how they can be sped up. Or, help me decide that it must be that my recursion is not the best strategy.

```
# Input is a list, representing the given sequence, e.g. L = [4,5,6]

def T(L): 
    limit = 10**9 + 7  # answer is returned modulo 10**9 + 7
    N = len(L)
    if N == 1: 
        return L[0]
    else:
        last = L[-1] 
        K = L[:N-1]
        ans =  T(K)%limit + 10*T(K)%limit + (last%limit)*pow(2,N-1,limit)
        return ans%limit
```

Comment: Well, due to the way you've named your variables, that is aggressively unreadable.  (and no, recursion is probably not the best strategy here)

Comment: Is 46 a legitimate subsequence ? It's broken by 5.

Comment: This is a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @roippi, This is my first post on stackoverflow and I am new to coding. Can you give some tips on how to better name the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my submission for the same problem (Manasa and Sub-sequences). 
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-may14/challenges/manasa-and-sub-sequences

I hope this will help you to think of a better way.

```
ans = 0
count = 0
for item in raw_input():
    temp = (ans * 10 + (count + 1)*(int(item)))%1000000007
    ans = (ans + temp)%1000000007
    count = (count*2 + 1)%1000000007

print ans
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is incredibly helpful. Since we have the same recursion I suppose my code was too slow because I read in all the integers and *then* did the calculations, whereas you did the calculations at the time of reading.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want the combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

def all_combinations(iterable):
    for r in range(len(digits)):
        yield from combinations(digits, r+1)
```

And you want to convert them to integers:

```
def digits_to_int(digits):
    return sum(10**i * digit for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(digits)))
```

And you want to sum them:

```
sum(map(digits_to_int, all_combinations([4, 5, 6])))
```

*Then* focus on speed.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of itertools. I think "yield from" is only in Python 3, is that correct?

Comment: 3.3 and higher, yes. `yield from y` is (almost) equivalent to `for x in y: yield x`, so it's not a big deal if you're stuck in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean continuous subsequence.

```
test = [4, 5, 6]

def coms(ilist):
    olist = []
    ilist_len = len(ilist)
    for win_size in range(ilist_len, 0, -1):
        for offset in range((ilist_len - win_size) + 1):
            subslice = ilist[offset: offset + win_size]
            sublist  = [value * (10 ** power) for (power, value) in enumerate(reversed(subslice))]
            olist.extend(sublist)
    return olist

print sum(coms(test))
```

Comment: Continuous subsequence is not what is meant.

Comment: The OP should change to *combinations* then.